# How can I block execution of rm -rf * in a Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, rm

I have a habit of typing `rm -rf *` every time I'm in some kind of sleep mode. It seems that my subconscious wants me to delete everything I code at the end of the day.

Is there a way to block this particular command (`rm -rf *`) in Linux in the C-shell or bash-shell?

Alternatively, is there a way in which I can set up a command filter for my shell inputs before it goes to the shell for further processing?

Comment: Don't sleep and code?

Comment: Break the habit rather than seek a technological solution. It's still and counter productive.

Comment: You seem to be searching technical solutions for psychological problems. Always try to solve a problem within its solution domain.

Comment: I second this, if you ever ssh into my box you might accidentally kill everything. NO GOOD!

Answer (score 5):

Check out [safe-rm](https://launchpad.net/safe-rm) which is a wrapper for `rm` that will allow you to set up a list of *important* directories that cannot be accidentally deleted.

This won't stop you from accidentally deleting files outside the listed directories, but it will prevent a  catastrophe when your subconscious decides to up the ante and do an `rm -rf /`.

---

That aside, the canonical way to prevent accidental deletion is to use `alias rm="rm -i"` as mentioned in several of the other answers.

*Extreme measures for extreme situations ...*

If you're subconscious is as malicious as it sounds, it can still bypass this by using `/bin/rm` instead to skip the alias. For some safeguard against this, create a file called `-i` in the directories you work in often:

```
[me@home]$ touch -- -i
[me@home]$ ls
-i    file1.txt    file2.txt
```

When evil-you does `/bin/rm -rf *`, the wildcard gets expanded to the list of files which starts with `-i`and that will be seen as an option by `/bin/rm`:

```
[me@home]$ /bin/rm -rf *
/bin/rm: remove regular empty file `file1.txt'?
```

(mouse-over the following block when your subconscious is not looking...)

> Now let's hope your subconscious is not aware of the `--` option...

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do that using the alias command. That's the same thing that e.g. converts `rm` to `rm -i` to prevent you from just deleting stuff without first confirming.

Comment: Quoting from the bash alias man page: `There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text.`

Comment: That same page also gives the example: $ alias rm='rm -i'

Comment: Which is good enough, because it doesn't use any of the arguments of `rm`, but introduces its own. The problem is that plain aliases can't determine if '-rf *' follows the `rm`

Comment: You make a valid point.

Comment: This will prevent `rm -r`, but not `rm -rf`. `-f` overrides `-i`.

Comment: @DanielBeck: One could write a wrapper around `rm` which would do the argument parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else is suggesting aliasing `rm` to `rm -i`.  This is normally a good solution.  The trouble is, it won't work in your case.  You always use `-rf` after `rm`.  Your command will become `rm -i -rf *`, and since the -f comes after the -i, it will override the -i.

You could write a wrapper that checks for `-rf` and prompts you before executing `rm`.

Answer (score 1):

While this may seem like a strange solution, I've occasionally aliased rm to a script that actually moves to a trash directory instead of removing. If you use the full path to rm you can still empty out that folder, but it solved the "What do you mean `rm` is permanent?" problem that I get with a lot of recent command line initiates.

Answer (score 0):

set up an alias for `rm` to go through a custom script of yours. It can check the command arguments (`-rf *`) and print an obnoxious prompt "ARE YOU FLIPPING SURE!?" otherwise it passes it through silently to `/usr/bin/rm` or whatever.

Comment: The custom script will never see the '*' because it has been expanded before.

Comment: Damn, you're right. I forgot that when I alias things like that I force the user to enter `*` as `"*"`

Answer (score 0):

This is not as easy as it seems, because the '*' is quickly expanded into a file/directory list. The `alias rm=rm -i` alias is probably the safest bet.

Answer (score 0):

tcsh, if you `set rmstar`, will ask for confirmation any time you invoke `rm` with a `*` argument.

Of course that requires using tcsh as your interactive shell; if you're already using bash, that's probably not a good enough reason to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Gigi sugested 'rm -i' but it will ask you **every time** you want to delete something.

My suggestion is to use the 'rm -I' - capital i - alias (alias rm=rm -I) quoting the man page:

```
          *once before removing  more  than  three  files,  or  when
          removing  recursively.  Less intrusive than -i, while still giv‐
          ing protection against most mistakes*
```

Comment: Have you tried this with typing `rm -rf`? `-f` should override this option.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to disable `rm` with this alias:

```
alias rm='echo "rm is disabled, use trash or /bin/rm instead."'
```

and to use `trash` instead of `rm`.
(The `trash` command can be found in the `trash-cli` package on Debian/Ubuntu)

If you don't like `trash`, you could also create an alias

```
alias remove='/bin/rm -irv'
```

and use `remove` instead of `rm`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal answer, but does exactly what you need in similar environment. To my knowledge, `bash` does not support this (at least not through `shopt`).

`zsh` delivers option to ask for confirmation when it sees `rm` used with an asterisk (regardless of flags used with this command).

From `man zshoptions`

> RM_STAR_SILENT (-H) `<K>` `<S>`
>
> Do not query the user before executing `rm *` or `rm path/*`.
>
> RM_STAR_WAIT
>
> If querying  the  user  before  executing `rm *` or `rm path/*`, first wait ten seconds and ignore anything typed in that
>   time.  This avoids the problem of reflexively answering `yes` to the
>   query when one didn't really mean it.  The wait and query can always
>   be avoided by expanding the `*` in ZLE (with tab).

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is the way bash will treat the * character in the command.  Normally, you could, for example, write your own "rm" script that filtered your input, but in this case the shell is going to treat the '*' as a [pattern and expand](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) it before handing the arguments off to whatever you write.

In this case, your best and only bet is to put an alias for rm in your .bashrc that will force-prompt your rm commands:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

Comment: No. ***DO NOT DO THIS***. If you're on a computer that doesn't have this, you'll be used to it and probably mess stuff up really badly.

Comment: That and it'd won't work, the -f will override the -i.

Answer (score -1):

`cd` into an empty directory first.  `rm -rf *` will then be harmless.

Comment: He wants to block it, not prevent it.